# PHP Laravel WebApp Booting Time >15 Seconds

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I run a laravel app on my website. Since I have expanded my database's one table 'places' to around 12GB in size, the booting time has increased drastically to ~12 seconds for HomePage and ~15 seconds for SearchPage which queries the 'places' table.

The 2 Images below are from HomePage's Debugbar

[Image from HomePage DebugBar Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohI6P.png)

[Image from HomePage DebugBar Queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1R9W.png)

The 2 Images below are from SearchPage's Debugbar

[Image from SearchPage DebugBar Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfSJT.png)

[Image from SearchPage DebugBar Queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRfjj.png)

---

I can also see that when I run
`php artisan`
in terminal of root folder, it takes around ~10 seconds before it displays results

For the above images, we can conclude that the database queries don't take long despite the size. It's just the booting time which takes the bigger chunk of the page loading time.

However, when I change the database to a low size one, the booting time is back to <1 sec. Wonders me where the problem is.

I have tried the basic approach to optimizations which includes
`php artisan optimize`
and checking if OPCache is enabled

Here's configurations of database: https://justpaste.it/csgo2

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables; SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;`

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is fixed by these 2 things -

1. Removing COUNT(*) queries being run during booting
2. Added Indexes from PHPMyAdmin on the Database Tables

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Added for you @WilsonHauck

Comment: OS version?  RAM size? # Cores? Any SSD or NVME on Host?  Can you post to justpaste.it  DB D) E) G) results?  Any OS requested available? particularly TOP reports and ulimit -a report and any others you can provide to assist with workload analysis.  Thanks

Comment: we can safely say that your database size and structure is the main reason why its slow. and with that, the improvement you could do would be 1. avoid using ORM/Eloquent, Use DB Facade and use the most optimize query with less overhead. 2. set-up proper indexes on columns that are heavily use for querying. play around with different query and different index in your local envi set-up until you get the one with acceptable performance.

Comment: @silver why do you think that - the last image shows the page loading in ~16s, but the longest query only takes ~3 seconds.  So there is still almost 13s to load the app.  The only thing that could affect this is if the database is in a different location and the connection is really slow.

Comment: @NigelRen I take it from what he said "However, when I change the database to a low size one, the booting time is back to <1 sec. Wonders me where the problem is." and his memory usage is around 79MB, which indicates he's either querying a lot of data, or he's doing a lot memory intensive computation after the query or both. plus debugbar also slows down his app.

Comment: Kartik Gurmule  Can you post - OS version? RAM size? # Cores? Any SSD or NVME on Host? Can you post to justpaste.it DB D) E) G) results? Any OS requested available? particularly TOP reports and ulimit -a report and any others you can provide to assist with workload analysis. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that is taking a lot of time is:

```
SELECT * FROM 'places' WHERE category LIKE '%2184%' AND city_id= 1 LIMIT 16 OFFSET 0;
```

My best guess is that `category` field isn't indexed. See if your `places` table uses an index for `category`.

If your `category` field uses multiple category id's, see if you can use a many-to-many table instead. That will improve performance.

If your `category` field only uses category_id's, see if you can make it a foreign key, that will automatically index that column and improve performance.

If that column could refer to multiple tables, but only refers to one id for each record, create an index. It also will improve your performance.

Since you haven't described your table definition, these are my best guesses.

You also mention that your `php artisan` is slow.  Are you sure you are not executing database queries in `__constructor`'s (direct or indirect)? Since that would be a mistake. Your constructors are only to build your classes, not to query data nor to run any business logic.

Comment: The wildcards won't allow the index to be used if one exists. A full text index would be better

Comment: Full Text is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in development mode, I can understand, but if you are running in production that may be a serious problem with your app.

in your .env file set :

```
   APP_DEBUG=true
   APP_ENV=production
```

can you run:

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan event:cache
```

All of those commands, are juste to compare whether there is a significant change.

Comment: Does nothing new